# Converting data format from array of string into numbers

Tags: php

I have

```
$resultArray = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
json_encode($resultArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

as :
[["0.003,445.85"],...]

and I need data like this:

[[0.003,445.85],...]

When trying:

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
   $resultArray[] = explode(',', $row);
}
json_encode($resultArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I have got:

[null, null, ...]

How to achieve target?

Comment: [`Cannot reproduce`](https://3v4l.org/UM8sY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this your array

```
$resultArray = [
  ["0.003,445.85"],
  ["0.051,500.08"]
];

$result = array();
foreach($resultArray as $str) {
  $inner = array();
  foreach($str as $s) {
    $split = explode(',',$s);
    $inner = array_map('floatval',$split);
  }
  array_push($result,$inner);
}

echo json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Which result to

```
[
  [0.003,445.85],
  [0.051,500.08]
]
```

or if your example wrong and it's

```
$resultArray = [["0.003","445.85"]];
```

`json_encode` with `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` will works

Comment: Yeah! Many thanks. And one correction: array_push($result,$inner);